# C# - Retrieve data from Database and store in 2 dimension dictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq, dictionary

Hello I try to do something like **PHP** thing  that is retrieve data from database and store in 2 dimension collection (Dictionary) 
I'm not sure I write it correctly or not.

Let's say my database table  and expected structure result look like this (See the screenshot)

[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDwA3.png)

```
public ActionResult ShowBook()
{          
         var books = from v in db.Books
                        select v;

         Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> test = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
         foreach (var item in books)
         {

             test[item.Book_Type_ID][item.Author_ID] = item.Book_Name;
         }

         return .....

}
```

But I has this error

`System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:` 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

How could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary is 2-dimensional. When you initialize it

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> test = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

The first dimension is initialized, but not the second - i.e. `test` is an empty dictionary. So when you try to add a book title to a second-dimension dictionary, there isn't a dictionary for it to be added to yet. You need to check this condition first, and create an entry if it doesn't already exist:

```
var books = from v in db.Books select v;

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> test = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
foreach (var item in books)
{
    if (!test.ContainsKey(item.Book_Type_ID))
        test[item.Book_Type_ID] = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    test[item.Book_Type_ID][item.Author_ID] = item.Book_Name;
}
```

Comment: Great answer sir

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have to initialize each inner `Dictionary<string, string>` when assigning a new key to your outer dictionary.  Typically this means checking if this key exists, and if not, creating the object:

```
foreach (var item in books)
{
      if(!test.ContainsKey(item.Book_Type_ID))
      {
           test[item.Book_Type_ID] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      }

      //now we are sure it exists, add it     
      test[item.Book_Type_ID][item.Author_ID] = item.Book_Name;
}
```